# If a vehicle with constant velocity hits me then is it correct to say that the vehicle exerted no force upon me and therefore I am unhurt?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, collision

Consider the scenario where a vehicle moving at a constant velocity collides with me and maintains it's constant velocity during the collision. What I think is that I may get hurt, which is just practical thinking. But I also think that I shouldn't be hurt, for the acceleration of the vehicle is zero, so there is no force acting upon me.

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Comment: Clarify "maintains it's constant velocity during the collision".

Comment: How can you say that the vehicle maintains the constant velocity? The only way that can happen is if you have zero mass. Your question is self-contradictory because you will accelerate the vehicle opposite the velocity.

Comment: @BillN You are forgetting that cars have gas pedals

Comment: @AaronStevens Yes, I understand that. I wasn't sure the OP considered that. I was trying to get OP to think about collisions and one would need to add work/impulse to the system and accelerate the car during the impact.

Comment: @BillN Oh ok. I must have misunderstood because you said the only way to achieve this was for the person to have no mass. In any case the OP isn't asking about the specifics of how to get this to happen.

Comment: For experiments, trains have a front surface with constant speed, and for low speeds, there is experimental evidence that it hurts. For very high speeds, anecdotally, the geometry of test mass becomes unstable, and it does not hurt.

Answer (score 7):

Even if the car's acceleration is $0$, you are greatly misusing Newton's second law here. $F=ma$ means that the acceleration of an object is proportional to the *net* force acting *on that same object*. $F=ma$ does *not* mean if an object isn't accelerating then it can't exert forces on anything else.

If the car is not accelerating while hitting you, then all Newton's second law tells you is that the net force *acting on the car* is $0$. In other words, the force the engine supplies to the car is equal and opposite to the force your body exerts on the car as it hits you. It doesn't say anything about the force the car exerts on other objects. i.e. $a=0$ doesn't mean the car can't apply forces to other objects.

Now, focusing on you, certainly as the car is hitting you it is exerting a force on you. By Newton's second law this gives you an acceleration which will definitely hurt you. By Newton's third law, this force the car exerts on you is equal and opposite to the force you exert on the car that was brought up in the previous paragraph.

Comment: the problem with his scenario is that it violates conservation of momentum. The car will accelerate as there is nothing that's perfectly rigid. If I jump I move the entire earth below me. I think you're answer should include conservative of momentum because it makes it clear why a person gets hurt by a moving car

Comment: @Andrew If you push on the gas you can maintain a constant velocity in the car. Momentum definitely does not need to be conserved for you to get hurt.

Comment: If you push on the gas then your acceleration is not zero. Unless you are assuming some idealized situation where the gas is pressed instantaneously at the moment of impact

Comment: @Andrew If you push on the gas *while you collide with the person* you can match the forces so that the acceleration of the car during the collision is $0$. The "idealness" of this scenario isn't really an issue. It would be physically possible to cause this to happen, even if it is not practically possible. I am analyzing the physical scenario given by the OP, not commenting on its practicality.

Answer (score 0):

The vehicle's constant velocity prior to collision is not relevant. If you are hit by the car, then you will exert an impact on the car, which means that the car will have an acceleration (deceleration) as a result of the collision (since neither the engine nor the wheels can exert and equal an opposite restoring force to match the impact). The deceleration of the car may be small (since its mass is much greater than yours) but momentum is conserved in collision, so it cannot be zero.

Comment: "Neither the engine nor the wheels can exert and equal an opposite restoring force to match the impact" - why not? With a powerful enough engine and a long enough collision, it's theoretically possible for the engine to apply an impulse that exactly counters the change in momentum. The driver can maintain a constant speed through the collision just by hitting the gas.

Answer (score 0):

The vehicle can only maintain its constant velocity throughout the collision by applying additional engine power, so that the net sum of tyre thrust less impact force remains constant.

Without additional engine power, the vehicle will necessarily be slowed down by the impact.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you stand on a railway line and are hit head-on by a massive train travelling at 100 kph. Do you imagine you would not be hurt? The train's velocity might be hardly changed by the collision, but yours definitely would. The force acting on you would be enormous, as your velocity would change in an instant from zero to 100kph. The fact that the train's speed is not changed is irrelevant- it is the force acting on you which causes the damage.

Answer (score 0):

it has 3 scenarios:
1/ you travelled at same speed with the car, then it'll make no hurt on you, F=0N.
2/ you're standing on a roller skates, so your body will get a force F=ma(m: your weight, a is acceleration from 0 to car's speed, skip the friction)
3/ you stay at the wall, so the car will abruptly stopped. this is the worst scenario. The acceleration is huge.The force will be: F=ma(m: the car's weight, a = maximum, ex.100km/s^2). then you will go nowhere, no hurt anymore...:))

Answer (score -3):

U may get hurt since the acceleration of the car is zero but with constant velocity higher than yours, therefore the Force acting on you getting hit will be much unless you walk with the same velocity.